# Basic CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

I have two pictures, one with an "onclick" function that disappears and in place another picture appears.  I'm just trying to figure out the code which will make one div (#b1) appear to the left of the second (#b2) and have them be at an even level, and when clicked #f1 will appear in place of #b2, but with compensation for the size of the image to the left of it.  My problem was that I had image overlapping and I want their positions to adjust.

What I had:

```
#b1 { position:absolute;  }
#b2 { position:relative; left:500px;}
#f1 { position:relative; left:500px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#b1, #b2, #f1 {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you position things absolutely, those things are removed from the document "flow" and cannot affect the position of anything else on the page. You'll have to manually detect collisions and adjust positions using JS, or restructure your html so that some parent container is positioned absolutely and the images are within this container, positioned relatively.